# Extending length of search bar in ArcGIS Online web mapping application

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-webmap

I am looking to be able to have a longer search bar to add more text to for my web map through ArcGIS's Web mapping application.  I am using the out of the box search widget, and I can't find anything through the widget itself, so I was wondering if there is any way to extend it?

[image: Search Bar]

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the width of `.esri-search` in your CSS

```
.esri-search {
    width: 1000px!important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the response.  I have never edited this before, and am not sure where to find this with in the script.  I tried looking and was unable to find it.  Can you direct me to what it is under in the script?

Comment: @Almost_There, maybe I am mistaken. Which technology for map creation do you use exactly? Do you have access to the CSS file or script of it?

Comment: I used the web app builder.  I can expose the script in google chrome and it seems I can edit it.

Comment: Editing in chrome is only for exactly your current site loading. Is your app stored somewhere where you can edit it? Is it on your server or ArcGIS Online or something else?